# Writing user data to a file

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to create a program that ask for sales amount and displays total salary and writes the entry to a file.  However my program has is only writing the last entry to the file.  I have searched online for 2hours for a solution and cant find one.

I want all of the input to write to my file not just the last one

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    void SavingFile(); //Declartion
    void Calculate();

    char FileName[20];
    double GrossPay;
    double TotalSalary;
    int employeeID=0;
    char response;
    int i=1;

    int main()

    {


    SavingFile();

    }


    void SavingFile()
    {


    cout << "\nEnter the name of the file you want to create: ";
    cin >> FileName;


      do

   {
       employeeID++;
     cout << endl << endl << "Enter sales amount for sales person ID " << employeeID <<" :                $";

      cin >> GrossPay;

      Calculate();

        cout <<"Sales amount for ID " << employeeID <<" : $" << TotalSalary <<endl;

        cout <<endl <<endl;




   do
    {

     ofstream Employee(FileName);
     Employee <<"Employee ID: "<< employeeID  <<" Sales Amount: $" << TotalSalary <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    i++;
    }
    while

        (employeeID == i);




      cout << "Do you want to process another employee ? (y/n): ";

      cin >> response;

    }

   while ( (response == 'Y') || (response == 'y') );

   }



    void Calculate()  // definition

    {

    TotalSalary = (GrossPay * .10) + 150;
    //return TotalSalary;
   }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and click on the orange ? (Markdown Editing Help) to find out how to improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: writing to a file is pretty formulaic. You need to make sure you get all the info stored somewhere (a list, array, whatever). Once you get all the info in there you iterate through it and write whatever you want even funny dark non-sequitur stuff.

Comment: do the formatting and also your `int main()` should return some `integer` value. So atleast use `return 0;` at the end of `main()`

Comment: Have you looked into Boost.Serialization or altogether SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the file every time you write to it.
If you want to append to the file, you need to open the file using the `ios_base::app` flag in addition to `ios_base::out`.

In your code, you must replace this:

```
ofstream Employee(FileName);
```

with this:

```
ofstream Employee(FileName, ios_base::out | ios_base::app);
```

To learn more, you can read [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) on the constructor of the `ofstream` class. Among other things, you will find a description of the various flags you can use and what they mean.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU...this worked perfectly.  you have saved me another 2 hours of frustration.  I have one other question.  How do i get rid of the "Process return ... Execution time " message that displays when i terminate my progress.  This is more of a personal/formatting issue.  I am kind of a perfectionist :) and not fond of the way it looks.  Thank you again.

Comment: By googling, I found out that that message is printed out when you use CodeBlocks to run your program. You need to look in the CodeBlocks options to see if there is a way to disable it. But if you run your program separately, not trough CodeBlocks, you won't get that message.

Comment: Thank you. I will look in the Code Block settings

Answer (score 0):

I won't rewrite your code for you, but I'll explain the logic that you need to rewrite.

In a loop, you read a value, and call `Calculate`, which sets a global variable called `TotalSalary`.  The `cout` probably looks ok.  Try adding a `cout` into the while loop where you are outputting the file, and you'll see that the values aren't what they used to be.

The problem is that every time you call `Calculate`, you overwrite `TotalSalary`.  You're not saving these values anywhere, but by looping through, you're assuming that the values are still there.

The solution is to write to the output file at the same time as you write to your `cout`.  Open the `ofstream` at the top of `main`, and just output to there like you are outputting to cout.

There's no need to open the file each time in a loop, and in fact you shouldn't.  (Though appending would help, if that's what you should have been doing.)